# What way can I implement to remove the vertical scrollbar from the page I'm designing?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<div>
                <body class="m-0 p-0 h-fit justify-center items-center min-h-screen font-['Jost',sans-serif] bg-gradient-to-b   from-[#0F0C29] via-[#302B63] to-[#24243E] overflow-hidden flex">
            <div class="main w-[350px] h-[580px] bg-red-600 overflow-hidden rounded-[10px] shadow-[5px_20px_50px_rgb(0,0,0)] bg-[url('C:\Users\Althaf\Desktop\Worxa\frontend\src\components\icon\FormBackground.jpg')]">
                <input class="hidden" type="checkbox" id="chk" aria-hidden="true"></input>
            <div class="signup relative w-[100%] h-[100%]">
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <label class="text-[#fff] text-[2.3em] justify-center flex m-[25px] font-bold cursor-pointer transition duration-300 ease-in-out" for="chk" aria-hidden="true">Sign up</label>
                <input class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#e0dede] justify-center flex my-[20px] mx-auto p-[10px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px]" type="text" placeholder="Name" name='name' id='name' required="" value={name} onChange={onChange} />
                <input class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#e0dede] justify-center flex my-[20px] mx-auto p-[10px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px]" type="date"placeholder="Date of Birth" required="" name='dob'id='dob' value={dob} onChange={onChange} />      
                <input class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#e0dede] justify-center flex my-[20px] mx-auto p-[10px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px]" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" name='phone' id='phone' required="" value={phone} onChange={onChange} />
                <input class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#e0dede] justify-center flex my-[20px] mx-auto p-[10px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px]" type="email" placeholder="Email" name='email' id = 'email' required="" value={email} onChange={onChange} />
                <select class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#e0dede] justify-center flex my-[20px] mx-auto p-[10px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px]" type="text" placeholder="Location" name='location' id = 'location' required="" value={location} onChange={onChange} > 
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select an Option</option>
                {
                    locations.map((location,i)=>{
                        return(
                            <option>{location.city}</option>
                        )
                    })
                }
                </select>
                <input class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#e0dede] justify-center flex my-[20px] mx-auto p-[10px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px]" type="Password" placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' required="" value={password} onChange={onChange}/>
                <input class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#e0dede] justify-center flex my-[20px] mx-auto p-[10px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px]" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name='ConfirmPassword' id='Confirm Password' required="" value={ConfirmPassword} onChange={onChange}/>
                <button class="w-[60%] h-[35px] bg-[#573b8a] justify-center block my-[10px] mx-auto p-[10px] font-bold text-[1em] mt-[20px] border-none outline-none rounded-[5px] transition ease-in duration-[0.2s] cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#6d44b8] text-[#fff]">Sign up</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </body>
            </div>
```

**Im trying to design a sign up page using tailwind css but when i use flex align items to center property the whole form gets in the center of the website with a vertical scrollbar Im unable to remove the vertical scrolling. Itd be really if anyone could suggest some way to get rid of it.**

Comment: well you would use `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: It is not working I tried it @Mordor

Comment: did you add !important before the semicolon ?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to find the scrollbar. Although,
you can `hide` the scrollbar by adding this utility in `index.css` file.

```
@layer utilities {
    /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    .no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }

    .no-scrollbar {
      -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
      scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    }
}
```

Then you just add the class `no-scrollbar`  in the div you want.